# How to show top header when we click on navbar item?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have one page with multiple section. When I click on menu item it goes to specific section but it hide header. All code for header is exist if we inspect page.
Code for Top menu is

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li tabindex="0"><a href="/en/">Home</a></li>
   <li tabindex="0"><a href="/en/#who-should-attend">Who should attend? 
   </a></li>
   <li tabindex="0"><a href="/en/#agenda">Agenda</a></li>
   <li tabindex="0"><a href="/en/#facilitators">Facilitators</a></li>
   <li tabindex="0"><a href="/en/#faq">FAQ</a></li>
   <li tabindex="0"><button type="button" id="LoginBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-whatever="@LoginModal" data-target="#LoginModal" class="btn btn-default" tabindex="0"><strong>Login</strong> </button></li>
   <!--<li><a href="/en/#about-us">About Us</a></li>-->
   <li tabindex="0">&nbsp;</li>
   <li tabindex="0"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.hellmann.com/en/" rel="noopener noreferrer"> <box-icon type="solid" name="home"></box-icon> </a></li>
   <li tabindex="0"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/hellmann-worldwide-logistics/mycompany/verification/" rel="noopener noreferrer"> <box-icon type="logo" name="linkedin-square"></box-icon> </a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please add your css code and an image so we can understand the issue better.

Comment: It's hard to tell without a snippet but looks like you're after a sticky header. Try searching stackoverflow for "fixed header" or "sticky header" and you will find lots of examples.